# Application hangs when run with Xcode but works fine otherwise

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator, nslog

For debugging purposes, I run the application using xcode and the UI freezes. If I run the app independently, the application works fine.

Could piping of NSLog statements to the console cause my application to hang?

Comment: Are you running on the device or the simulator?  Are you hitting a breakpoint somewhere?

Comment: Check the console for any message

Comment: It works fine on the simulator. The problem happens only with device and when run through XCode. If I don't runt the app through xcode, it works fine. I see the messages on console. I wanted to use xCode for debugging purposes.

Comment: Changed the debugger from lldb to gdb which seems to help most of the times.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed with the release of Xcode 4.4.1.  See the following bug report for description:

http://openradar.appspot.com/11972490